# How to format HTTP request to discord API?

Tags: python, sockets, http, https, discord

While this code works, it sends "Bad Request".

```py
import socket, ssl
token = 'NzMyMzQ1MTcwNjK2MTR5OEU3.XrzQug.BQzbrckR-THB9eRwZi3Dn08BWrM'
HOST = "discord.com"
PORT = 443
t = 'POST / HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthentication: Bot {token}\r\nHost: discord.com/api/guilds/{702627382091186318}/channels\r\n\r\n'
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOST)
s_sock.connect((HOST, 443))
s_sock.sendall(t.encode())

f = s_sock.recv(7000).decode()
print(f)

s_sock.close()
```

**Note**: this is not a real token.

Comment: What does `/guilds/{702627382091186318}/channels` mean?

Comment: The number is a guild ID. It is used to fetch information from a certain guild.

Comment: Do you have those curly brackets (`{}`) in the request? They're not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> t = 'POST / HTTP/1.0\r\nAuthentication: Bot {token}\r\nHost: discord.com/api/guilds/{702627382091186318}/channels\r\n\r\n'
> ```

This is not a valid HTTP request. You essentially send (line breaks added for clarity):

```
 POST / HTTP/1.0\r\n
 Authentication: Bot {token}\r\n
 Host: discord.com/api/guilds/{702627382091186318}/channels\r\n
 \r\n
```

But a correct POST request would look like this instead:

```
 POST /api/guilds/{702627382091186318}/channels HTTP/1.0\r\n
 Authentication: Bot {token}\r\n
 Host: discord.com\r\n
 Content-length: ...
 \r\n
 <body, where size matches Content-length header>
```

I.e. you have the wrong path, wrong `Host` header, missing body and missing `Content-length` header. If you really want to write your own HTTP stack instead of using existing libraries please study the standards instead of just guessing how it might look - that what standards are for.

Comment: I am not able to update my post, but  thank you so much for the help! It works!